# Specific transistor for voltage regulating?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, npn

In 2SD1047 NPN transistor [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/2sd1047.pdf) described the application for **power supplies** and the description is:

> The device is a NPN transistor manufactured using new BiT-LA (Bipolar
>   transistor for linear amplifier) technology. The resulting transistor
>   shows good gain linearity behavior.

- How do we know which transistors used the "BiT-LA technology"? is it described somewhere in the datasheet?
- Does it really make a difference between this transistor and for example a general purpose transistor like [2N3055](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3055-D.PDF) (I know the packages are different but what about the performance)?
- Which specifications makes a transistor ideal for using it as main voltage regulating transistor in power supplies?

Comment: It's standard page 1 marketing hype.

Comment: @Andyaka So there's no difference in general?

Comment: Have you been to the ST site and looked to see if they list this technology?

Comment: @Andyaka Searching the keyword "BiT-LA" in st.com just shows the 2SD1047 as a single transistor product.

Comment: The 2STC5949 also used it but, I think you can assume that given it wasn't a widespread solution to all but the audiophile brigade, then it's marketing hype. Oh, the 2STA2121 uses it too. Same answer, hype.

Comment: Gain varies with a lot of things including collector current and temperature. If this technology is something other than hype, there should be some curves showing that the variation of gain (beta) with temp and collector current is superior to other transistors such as the 2N3055 (which is ANCIENT, by the way!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the flatness of output I_V collector characteristics will affect linearity and power-supply-rejection ability, I'd expect the Early Voltage to be a key parameter for audio power devices.

And the size of the high_current contacts down into the silicon may also matter; this requires slightly larger metallization which requires more silicon. Another way to do this is with additional bond_wires, which definitely increases cost (slightly).

==================================

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect

A large EARLY VOLTAGE tells the designer that particular bipolar transistor is a more constant current source as the Vce varies.

Comment: What is "early voltage"?